# Error en programa que convierte números de octal a decimal con recursividad

Tags: java

Hola e intentado hacer un programa con recursividad que convierta números **octal a decimal**. Y no lo e logrado, no se si puedan ayudarme. Se que esta mal, pero lo e intentado de varias formas y hasta el momento en esto me quede, espero contar con su asesoría.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
    String num;
    int num2,octal = 0,c = 0;
    System.out.println("Introduzca un numero");
    num = leer.next();

    if(num.length() == 1){
       num2 = Integer.parseInt(num);
       octal = num2;
        System.out.println("su numero en decimal es " + octal);
    }else{
    convertir(num,octal,c);
    }   
 }

public static int convertir(String num, int octal, int c){
    int num3;
    if(c < num.length()){ 
    //num.charAt(c);
    String num2 = Character.toString(num.charAt(c));
    num3 = Integer.parseInt(num2);
    octal = octal + (num3 * 8 * convertir(num,octal,c + 1));
    }
    return octal;
}

}
```

Comment: Agrega lo que has intentado.

Comment: no es buena práctica el decir "quiero esto" así sin más, en Stack overflow, esperamos que muestres tu empeño en lo que haces, así que, no esperes muchas respuestas si no muestras al menos que llevas de progreso, te recomendaria que vayas a [edit] y agregues tu código, bienvenido :D